# How do I run a statement after multiple functions are done with random timeouts?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I got this code:

```
'use strict';

var total = 0;

console.log("Start of program - total is now: " + total);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("function 1");
    total += 10;
}, 500);


setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("function 2");
    total += 50;
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));


setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("function 3");
    total += 100;
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));


console.log("End of progam - total is now: " + total);
```

How would I run the last console.log only when all the timeouts above it are executed?

Comment: Check out [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object, if you need better support you can use [jQuery.promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: I may not use API's only pure Javascript, thanks for the information. Will read it.

Comment: Promise is pure javascript, although not widely supported yet.

Comment: Without promises, there's no real way to see if the timeout function completed.  I guess you could make an array and add to it once the function completes.  Then poll using `setInterval` until that array is full.  That's just one idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possible ways to tackle this. I would recommend, if you have some time, looking into Promises, and using Promise.all().

However, if you're sticking to just using vanilla callbacks, I replace the console.log with the following:

```
var countTimeoutsFinished = 0;
function testEndOfProgram() {
    if(countTimeoutsFinished === 3) {
        console.log("End of program - total is now: " + total);
    }
}
```

and then, inside each timeout, increment countTimeoutsFinished and call testEndOfProgram():

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("function 1");
    total += 10;
    countTimeoutsFinished++;
    testEndOfProgram();
}, 500);
```

. When the 3rd timeout completes, countTimeoutsFinished will be 3, and when you then get into testEndOfProgram the console.log will execute.

Comment: I had a similar idea, except I was thinking of calling `testEndOfProgram` in a `setInterval`.  This is a better idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises, as said by Kyle.

Running example with jQuery (just to simplify, you can use any Promise library)

var total = 0;

```
console.log("Start of program - total is now: " + total);

var dfd1 = new jQuery.Deferred();
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("function 1");
    total += 10;
    dfd1.resolve();
}, 500);


var dfd2 = new jQuery.Deferred();
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("function 2");
    total += 50;
    dfd2.resolve();
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));


var dfd3 = new jQuery.Deferred();
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("function 3");
    total += 100;
    dfd3.resolve();
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));

$.when.apply($, [dfd1, dfd2, dfd3])
.done(function() {
   alert("End of progam - total is now: " + total); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3r0ydxg5/

Comment: I appreciate your time in answering me, I can't use a library as I need to use pure Javascript. But I will remember this when I can use Jquery. Thanks!

Comment: There are some Promise's pure libraries, like Q, when, etc... You can take a look at: http://complexitymaze.com/2014/03/03/javascript-promises-a-comparison-of-libraries/

Comment: Also, Promises are starting to be natively supported in browsers, so soon you won't need a library at all to use them!